# Div doesn't show by just changing name?

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing with web development and I have a very weird problem with HTML and CSS.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #71c7d1, #417e8a);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
}

#banner {
    right: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}

#friendRequests {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}

#friendsList {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatscreen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><h1>Welcome to your TicTac</h1></div>
        <!--<div id="friendRequests"></div>-->
        <div id="friendRequests"></div>
        <div id="chatScreen"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, #friendsList and #friendRequests are exactly the same. Note the line after the div that has been commented out, it has the id friendRequests. When I load the page, the div doesn't show up. But here is where I get confused. If I change the id of that div to friendsList, it does show up, but those two identities have exactly the same properties (I did this just to debug, friendRequests will have other properties). I even commented the friendsList out in CSS and I even removed it, it still doesn't change. Can someone explain to me why this apparently only depends on the name of the id? Thanks!

Big Update:
Apparently the script works perfectly fine in Microsoft Edge, so the problem lies in Chrome. Using Element Inspector, I discovered that the #friendRequests is actually never loaded in Chrome!! What might be the issue here?

Comment: Your 2 divs might be overlapping over one another.
Try removing position:absolute?

Comment: Hi There, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I tried a lot of things, I even removed the div that might be overlapping the other. I also tried to work with relative positions. It really appears  that the problem lies in the name

Comment: Its unclear how the final output will look like based on your question. Please draw a picture or add more information on how you want them to look like :)

Comment: `id` must be unique for each element on the page. otherwise you will have alot of issues moving on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The final plan is for friendRequests to appear on the right. I put them both on the left to see what the issue is. I commented out the first div that should be on the left, to only have one div on the left.I've changed the id of the div with id friendRequests that isn't commented to both friendRequests and friendsList. It only shows up when I use friendsList, not when I use friendRequests, however, the properties are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Both divs `#friendsList` and `#friendRequest` are set with `position: absolute;` and `float: left;`.
This means both will be aligned to the left side of the screen regardless of other elements. As a consequence, both divs are on top of each other and only one is visible (specifically the one which is defined later in html).

You should remove the `position: absolute` from the divs. Or make them relative, so they are aligned next to each other, depending on the order in the html.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #71c7d1, #417e8a);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
}

#banner {
    right: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

#friendRequests {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#friendsList {
    float: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatscreen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><h1>Welcome to your TicTac</h1></div>
        <div id="friendRequests"></div>
        <div id="friendsList"></div>
        <div id="chatScreen"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for the time for responding. I've commented out the div that would overlap the other. Originally, I wanted friendRequests to be on the right, but the div didn't show up. I placed them both left to see whether the problem was the name. Note that the first div that should be placed on the left is commented out.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is both the div are having same css when you use the same id because of which the divs are overlapping on each other.

The id should be unique.

To understand the difference, I have shifted "friendRequests 2" block a bit left.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #71c7d1, #417e8a);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
}

#banner {
    right: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}

#friendRequests {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}

#friendsList {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #3231ff;
}
.left_block{
    left: 21%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatscreen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><h1>Welcome to your TicTac</h1></div>
        <div id="friendRequests">friendRequests 1</div>
        <div id="friendRequests" class="left_block">friendRequests 2</div>
        <div id="chatScreen"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Id attribute must be **unique**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: That, I am aware of but here the question is why it is overlapping that I explained here

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I've commented out the first div, so there should be no overlapping?

Comment: No, if you are commenting the first div there should be no overlapping. Can you explain a bit more what structure is required. What I can understand is  one div should be right corner and another to be left. Is that so

Comment: Hi, I actually discovered what the problem is, it isn't my script, it's Chrome. When loading this in Edge, it works perfectly fine. Using Elements Inspector, I discovered that the CSS file isn't loaded fully, when I post the #friendRequests in Elements Inspector, it does work however. Also, refreshing the page also doesn't update the script. So I have to investigate that

Comment: Yeah, seems like debugging is required for this.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for answering, I found the solution. The problem wasn't the script, it was my browser apparently. Like I commented a few times, loading the page in Edge worked perfectly fine. I discovered using the debugger tool that the CSS file wasn't loaded completely for one or another reason. Thus I suspect this might be a bug in Chrome.